# Rails: импорт фото из csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

В приложении есть **product**:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, :content, presence: true
  validates_length_of :photos, maximum: 5
end
```

Фото к ним сделаны как вложеные ресурсы. **photo.rb:**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Пытаюсь импортировать продукты из csv:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol,col_sep: '||') do |row|
  Product.create!( 
    :title=> row[1],
    :content=> row[2],

    :photos_attributes => {
      row[3].each do |img|
        :image => img
      end
     }

  )
end
```

Ошибка:
.../app/models/product.rb:322: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end :image => img ^ 
.../app/models/product.rb:323: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Пример csv:

```
title||content||img name
Товар 1 || Описание товра 1 || "[""img_1.jpg"", ""img_4.jpg"", ""img_5.jpg""]"
Товар 2 || Описание товра 2 || "[""img_1.jpg"", ""img_2.jpg"", ""img_3.jpg""]"
Товар 3 || Описание товра 3 || "[""img_1.jpg"", ""img_5.jpg""]"
Товар 4 || Описание товра 4 || []
```

При импорте картинок возникает 2 проблемы:
 - как создать сразу несколько фото
 - как правильно загрузить файл в rails?

Comment: Ну надо файл открывать IO.read и его уже епредавать как image

Comment: А что за модель Advert?

Comment: @cheops пардон. поправил

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ как там перебор сделать правильно? т.к. фото в csv как хэш вставлено.

Comment: @alexin как что? покажите в посте

Comment: `:image => row[3]`. row[3] это хэш к примеру: `"[""img_1.jpg"", ""img_4.jpg"", ""img_5.jpg""]"`. т.е. получается на 1 продукт надо  создать 3 фото.   `row[3].each do |img| :photos_attributes => { :image => row[3] } end` но ругается на синтаксис `syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end :image => img ^`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В аттрибутах фото нужно указать не просто имя файла, а прямо загрузить оный:

```
photos_attributes: row[3].map { |img| { image: IO.read(img) } }
```

есть также вариант использовать [класс загрузчика `rack`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/Test/UploadedFile) так:

```
Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("me.jpg", "image/jpeg")
```

Comment: спасибо за совет. но при такой записи возникает ошибка `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' ...utes: row[3].map { |img| image: IO.read(img) } ... ^`. пробовал переписать в виде `:photos_attributes => { row[3].map { |img| image: IO.read(img) } }` , но в этом случае тоже ошибка: `.../app/models/advert.rb:323: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' row[3].map { |img| image: IO.read(img) } ^
.../app/models/advert.rb:323: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>`

Comment: работает) челом бью, боярин!

Comment: плохо вчера проверил.  при загрузке csv ошибка `No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` . проблема именно в загрузке фото. если эту строку убрать все создается правильно.

Comment: @alexin обновил